# Yocto - development build vs production build

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'd like to have a traditional way to build a development image and a production image, both pulling from the same recipes, but one differing with just debug tools/settings.

I've read that conditional includes in builds is not really how Yocto/Bitbake work, but thought perhaps the easiest way is to create a separate MACHINE folder, but perhaps have the debug work directory point to an additional layer with the debug stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write two separate image recipes, and have them include what is needed (e.g. additional debug-oriented recipes).

Comment: Short of copy/paste, how do I create the debug image recipe? Can I just inherit the first somehow?

Comment: You put the common bits into my-image.inc, and include that from my-image-production.bb and my-image-debug.bb. Then adjust either as needed by adding extra packages etc. Oe-core has plenty of examples for this, e.g. core-image-sato and core-image-sato-dev.

Comment: I have a similar issue.. I opened another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625668/yocto-development-image-with-bbappend-in-multiple-layers

Comment: @AlexanderKanavin can you share an example of how you solved this. Did you need to place anything into local.conf or bblayers.conf?

Comment: Please check: "Oe-core has plenty of examples for this, e.g. core-image-sato and core-image-sato-dev."