# Yocto development image with bbappend in multiple layers

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am writing an image description which I want to append on multiple layers
a bsp layer, a security layer and an application layer.

in bsp: I have image.bb and image-dev.bb with

```
require image.bb
```

on the other layers I have image.bbappend and image-dev.bbappend

```
require image.bbappend
```

does causes the error:

```
ERROR: ParseError in .../sources/meta-application/recipes-core/images/image.bbappend: not a BitBake file
```

When I build *image* the packages in image.bb and all image.bbappend are present

When I build *image-dev* the stuff in image.bb, image-dev.bb and all the image-dev.bbapend is present **Not the packages from image.bbappend**

bitbake -e image-dev yields:

```
# $IMAGE_INSTALL [21 operations]
#   set .../sources/poky/meta/conf/documentation.conf:212
#     [doc] "Specifies the packages to install into an image. Image recipes set IMAGE_INSTALL to specify the packages to install into an image through image.bbclass."
#   set .../sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:3
#     "packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL}"
#   set? .../sources/poky/meta/classes/core-image.bbclass:70
#     "${CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL}"
#   set? .../sources/poky/meta/classes/image.bbclass:70
#     ""
#   set .../sources/poky/meta/classes/image.bbclass:71
#     [type] "list"
#   _append .../sources/meta-bsp/recipes-core/images/image.bb:32
...
#   _append .../sources/meta-bsp/recipes-core/images/image-dev.bb:38
...
#   _append .../sources/meta-application/recipes-core/images/image-dev.bbappend:24
...
#   _append .../sources/meta-my-security/recipes-core/images/image-dev.bbappend:14
...
```

Any idea how to fully inherit/include the entire base image including all it's bbappends?!

Thank you!
Stefan

Comment: Check whether your image.bbappend file's folder name is added in bblayers.conf file.

Comment: try this command "bitbake-layers show-appends" and check whether your image.bbappend file is listed under image.bb

Comment: Do you properly manipulate `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable? Also check output of `bitbake -e image-dev` and check the appropriate variables and the process of assignment.

Comment: the bbappend files are there for image and image-dev


for the IMAGE_INSTALL I updated the original question

Comment: If you have `image.bbappend`, then the content is already appended to the `image.bb` file. So there is no reason to require the `.bbappend` file. And if you want to include/require file from different layer, use full path inside oe, i.e. `require recipes-core/images/image.inc`. Could you please test?

Comment: the image also has image.bbappend files in different layers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with the following structure:

```
/meta-bsp/recipes-core/images/image.bb
    ... base packages

/meta-bsp/recipes-core/images/image-dev.bb
    ... development packages (like vim/htop/tree...)



/meta-application/recipes-core/images/image.inc
    ... application packages

/meta-application/recipes-core/images/image.bbappend
    require image.inc

/meta-application/recipes-core/images/image-dev.bbappend
    require image.inc
    ... application testing programms



/meta-my-security/recipes-core/images/image.inc
    security packages

/meta-my-security/recipes-core/images/image.bbappend
    require image.inc

/meta-my-security/recipes-core/images/image-dev.bbappend
    require image.inc
    .. security testing packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `require image.bbappend` from file `image-dev.bbappend`

There is no need to require `image.bbappend` in `image-dev.bbappend`. `image.bb` already contains configurations from `image.bbappend` file. so adding `require image.bb` in `image-dev.bb` file is sufficient