# How to separate development tools from final image correctly in Yocto?

Tags: yocto, layer, bitbake, openembedded

My Yocto project currently contains both Poky Linux distro with my settings and with some mandatory software and some amount of debugging and development stuff, which I need only during debugging phase and I'd love to skip it from getting into final image. The problem is that there is a lot of packages I would love to skip and their list is changing all the time. So I need some sort of mechanics to have these packages only in dev phase but then I should have a 'magic button' to build a final image without all that debugging and development stuff.
What I think now of it is a separate directory of development and debug tools, built but not installed into final image - that directory can reside on my NFS server or whatever, but then I can install any RPM into final image after mounting that NFS with typical `rpm -iv ...`
I have no idea how I can specify correctly enough and in Yocto-polite way to build but not install packages into final image.
Could you please help me with that approach - how to build but not install packages in Yocto/BB recipes and place resulting RPM's into separate directory? Or, probably you can suggest me a better way of separating development tools and final image?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by way of using separate image recipes as briefly discussed in [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060639/yocto-development-build-vs-production-build).

For example, you could have a base image recipe (i.e. core-image-foo) that doesn't contain debug/development stuff. Then you could have another image recipe (i.e. core-image-foo-dev) that extends the base image recipe (by requiring it) with debug & development only stuff.

Comment: Thank you! I could not find anything suitable for me here and this topic you mentioned was out of my scope.